# Know if the "Issue" content type's fields are site columns or list columns

Tags: 2013, content-type, column

I access the "Issue" content type as follow:

[image]

But I want to know, for each field, if it is a site column or a list column. I can not find a way to differentiate between them.

Comment: @robert thanks for the edit ,, but do u have any idea about the problem i am facing ?

Comment: The "Source" columns shoud show a content type name if it is created from a content type. If it is a site column, you should be able to see from the URL when you edit a column where it sends you

Comment: @RobertLindgren can u advice more on this ? and is Unnie answer correct ? as i test it inside my list and i realized that the Description column inside the Issue content type is  a list column and not a site column, although it has its source set to Issue and it is not blank ... can u advice ?

Comment: In your screenshot you are in the Site Content Type dialog, so everything there is deployed on the site level,,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scenario 1: When you go to Site Settings --> Site Content Types -- > select any content types , then it will show you only Site columns, no list columns will be shown there.

[image]

Scenario 2: You have a list , which is using a content type. Go to List settings--> Under content types select the content type . Here it will show both Site columns and List columns. But for List columns the Source will be blank.

[image]

Edit:
 By default the Description column of Issue content type is not shown in site columns page (as it is present inside a hidden group). Please go to Site content types -- > Select Issue-- > Select Description --> Edit column and then edit

[image]

[image]

You can change the group , if you want it to be displayed in site columns page.

Comment: i do not think this is the case,becuase i have a column inside the Issue Content Type named "Description" , and if i go to the Site Column under the site settings,  i will also find two columns named "Description". so i rename the two site columns which i accessed from he (Site Setting>>Site Columns) , but this renaming was not reflected inside the Description field inside the Issue content type. so i conclude that the Description column inside the Issue content type , is a list column and not a site column, although it have a Source as shown in your picture. so cn u advice?

Comment: The Description column of Issue content type is present in a hidden group, so will not be seen in Site columns page by default.Go to Site content types --> Select Issue--> Description --> Edit column . Site content types cannot hold a List column , it will always have site columns. List content type will have both site column and list column.

Comment: so why my Description column inside the Issue content type, can not be updated from the (site setting>>site columns). For example Currently i have renamed the two site columns to be Description1 & Description2 from (site setting>>site column), but the Description column inside the Issue content type still have the same name "Description". but if i do the same thing for the "Issue Status", where i update the "Issue Status" column from (site setting>> site columns) and i rename it to "Issue Status2" , the  the "Issue Status" column inside the "Issue "content type will get renamed also?

Comment: Yes this is because by default the Description column of Issue content type is not shown in site columns page (as it is present inside a hidden group). Please go to Site content types -- > Select Issue-- > Select Description --> Edit column and then edit

Comment: so my test shows that the Issue Status is a site column , while the Description is a list column. although the Description column is displayed inside the "Issue" content type and it have its source set to "Issue" ?? i am really confused ?

Comment: I have edited my answer and added the screenshot,it might help.

Comment: aha i  just understand this ,,, so when i created an "Issue tracking" list which is based on the "Issue" content type,all the defualt columns are site columns including; title,description,due date, related issue, comment, issue status, category , priority .  so i got this concern seems that SharePoint will allow two site columns to have the same name ? because currently i got three site columns named "Description" ? but seems insdie each group the name is unique , is this correct ?